# How to use a form to fill in fields with the same value in the same table in Access 2016?

Tags: forms, ms-access, database-design, datatable, field

every1!

I have a table called JOBS that I fill in according to the new jobs I get. I believe I should have planned my table better, but my Access knowledge is not that good yet.

I would like to create a form (or whatever) that would help me avoid typing the same CLIENT_NAME for the different jobs. Sometimes I have 30 jobs for the same CLIENT_NAME.

Please note that I talking about one single table here. All I want to do is fill in this table, but without having to type the same CLIENT_NAME like 30 times.

Is that ever possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to avoid typing the same client name 30 times in a row, you can achieve that by just using the clipboard when you fill out the form.
After you type the name in the first time,  use CTRL-C to copy the name to the clipboard.  After that use CTRL-V to fill in the same name.

However, it sounds like you have a problem of harmful redundancy in the JOBS table.  This is the kind of thing that is solved by normalizing your table design.  You might not be ready to learn data normalization just yet.  But it behooves you to learning it before building a lot of databases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *AfterUpdate* event if the textbox bound to Client_Name to set its *DefaultValue*:

```vb
Private Sub Client_Name_AfterUpdate()

    If Not IsNull(Me!Client_Name.Value) Then
        Me!Client_Name.DefaultValue = Chr(34) & Me!Client_Name.Value & Chr(34)
    End If

End Sub
```